# Retieving sender profile through ssjs and soap

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi, cloudpagesurl

I am trying to retrieve sender profile by doing soap call via ssjs:

```
    Platform.Load("core","1");

var payload = '';
var endpoint = "https://mcrd367cfywzf2wz7gc7ln-dc7fq.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx";
var result;


payload += '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>;
payload += '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">;
payload += '<s:Header>;
payload += '<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>;
payload += '<a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://XXXX.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>;
payload += '<fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">XXXXXXX</fueloauth>;
payload += '</s:Header>;
payload += '<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">;
payload += '<RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">;
payload += '<Options>;
payload += '</Options>;
payload += '<RetrieveRequest>;
payload += '<ObjectType>SenderProfile</ObjectType>;

payload += '<Properties>ObjectID</Properties>;

payload += '<Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>;
payload += '<Properties>FromName</Properties>;
payload += '<Properties>FromAddress</Properties>;

payload += '<Properties>Description</Properties>;
        
payload += '<Properties>SenderHeaderEmailAddress</Properties>;
payload += '<Properties>SenderHeaderName</Properties>;
payload += '<QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>;
    
payload += '</RetrieveRequest>;
payload += ' </RetrieveRequestMsg>;
payload += ' </s:Body>;
payload += '</s:Envelope>;

try {
    result = HTTP.Post(endpoint,"text/xml",payload,["SOAPAction"],["Retrieve"]);
}

if (result.StatusCode != 200) {
    //Bad response
    Write(Stringify(result));
} else {
    //Good response
    Write(Stringify(result));
}
    </script>
```

But I am finding
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
after publishing and clicking on the cloudpage link.

Can anybody point out what is the problem in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to do this with the same error the user had in the comments of the other answer. After some fiddling around I removed the query all accounts line and it worked. Just sharing in case anyone else runs into this. You have to run it for every BU this way, I'll update if I get something to pull all results.

```
<script runat = "server" > Platform.Load("core", "1.1.5");
try {
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var cols = ["CustomerKey", "FromName", "FromAddress", "Description", "SenderHeaderEmailAddress", "SenderHeaderName"];
    var data = prox.retrieve("SenderProfile", cols)
    Write("Result: " + Stringify(data));
} catch (e) {
    Write(Stringify(e));
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

When using SSJS, it is *much* easier to interact with SOAP API objects using [WSProxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_useSSJS.htm). The example you've listed above could be written as the following:

```
<script runat = "server" >
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.5");
try {
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var queryAllAccounts = true;
    var cols = ["CustomerKey", "FromName", "FromAddress", "Description", "SenderHeaderEmailAddress", "SenderHeaderName"];
    var data = prox.retrieve("SenderProfile", cols, queryAllAccounts)
    Write("Result: " + Stringify(data));
} catch (e) {
    Write(Stringify(e));
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I have used the above code in cloudpage but I am having the following error :{"message":"Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.","description":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame. - from mscorlib\r\n\r\n"}

Comment: Are you including anything else on the cloudpage other than the above script? I've tested this and it executes as intended on my end.

Comment: No I am just using this code only but I am getting the above error

Comment: getting this while publishing :``{"message":"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.","description":"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. - from mscorlib --> \r\n\r\n --- inner exception 1---\r\n\r\nExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: WSProxy object is not valid in sendable content. This function is only allowed in non-sendable content.\r\n Object: Script.Util.WSProxy()\r\n Error Code: OMM_FUNC_CONTEXT_ERR\r\n - from OMMCommon\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"}

Comment: Are you seeing that error in the preview mode and not on the live/published page? There is an issue with the preview functionality such that, when running WS Proxy scripts like the above, it will always show that error in preview but the live site will execute the code correctly.

Comment: In preview mode i am seeing the above error , and  after publishing when clicked on the link , it is showing : {"message":"Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.","description":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame. - from mscorlib\r\n\r\n"}